# issue about custom a global UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uinavigationbar, global

I've customized a share button and put it in `UINavigationbar` to be a right bar button item, I want to click this button to present a `UIActivityViewController`, the code can be built successfully and run, but the share button cannot be clicked, nothing happens (even errors), just like the share button is disabled.

**The demo picture:**
[image]

Can anyone help me to solve it? Thank you in advance.

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

import Font_Awesome_Swift

class shareButton:UIButton{

var button:UIButton = UIButton()

init(button_frame: CGRect, connected: [UIButton]?){
    super.init(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    self.button.frame = button_frame
    self.button.setFAIcon(icon: FAType.FAShareAlt, iconSize: 22, forState: .normal)
    self.button.setFATitleColor(color: .darkGray)
    self.button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func construct() -> UIButton {
    return self.button
}

@objc func buttonPressed() {
    let url = NSURL.init(string: "http://www.probe-lab.com")
    let items:[Any] = [url!]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [.print,
                                                    .assignToContact,.saveToCameraRoll,.addToReadingList,.openInIBooks]
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
}
```

In viewcontroller I used the button like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let btn = shareButton(button_frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 30, height:30), connected:nil ).construct()
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item
}
```

Comment: Seeing how nothing happens when you tap on it, I'm guessing that either it's not enabled or its window/frame isn't set correctly. Anyway, why not just install the button in storyboard and link it to your code? Everything you're doing above can be done with storyboard

Comment: @dinosaysrawr, thank you for your reply. I wanna use this share button and action for many views, and now I have an answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution and modified my code, add "var strongSelf:shareButton?" and  "strongSelf = self", now it can run and present an activityViewController. I don't know if this is the best solution, but at least it works.
I found it works fine with iPhone devices and simulators but crashes with iPads, so add "activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = button" to solve it.

```
import UIKit
import Font_Awesome_Swift

class ShareButton:UIButton{

  var button:UIButton = UIButton()
  var strongSelf:ShareButton?

  init(button_frame: CGRect, connected: [UIButton]?){
   super.init(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
   self.button.frame = button_frame
   self.button.setFAIcon(icon: FAType.FAShareAlt, iconSize: 22, forState: .normal)
   self.button.setFATitleColor(color: .darkGray)
   self.button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
   strongSelf = self
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  func construct() -> UIButton {
   return self.button
  }

 @objc func buttonPressed() {
  let url = NSURL.init(string: "http://www.probe-lab.com")
  let items:[Any] = [url!]
  let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
  activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [.print,
                                                .assignToContact,.saveToCameraRoll,.addToReadingList,.openInIBooks]
  activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = button
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
   appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
  }
```

In any view I wanna use this  share button just add the lines like this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let btn = ShareButton(button_frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 30, height:30), connected:nil ).construct()
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please be sure to Capitalize class names. That is the convention in Swift. Now, moving on to the solution:

You don't need to subclass UIButton to do get your desired result.

Simply add the "buttonPressed" code as action for the barbuttonitem.

Trying to create a UIButton subclass that internally instantiates another UIButton and sends that button to the ViewController which then casts it into UIBarButtonItem is a very convoluted way of doing it.

You can download my solution from this repository:
https://github.com/asabzposh/StackOverFlow-48554026.git

If you desire to create a UIButton subclass, then do it this way:

```
import UIKit

class ShareButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {            
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // Set title, background color, etc.
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        let image = UIImage(named: "p.jpeg")
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        self.addSubview(imageView)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(internalButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    @objc func internalButtonPressed() {
        let url = NSURL.init(string: "http://www.probe-lab.com")
        let items:[Any] = [url!]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [.print, .assignToContact,.saveToCameraRoll,.addToReadingList,.openInIBooks]
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Then to use it in your ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       // 1. Solution A
       // let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Share", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(buttonPressed))

      // 2. Solution B
        let button = ShareButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        let item = UIBarButtonItem()
        item.customView = button

     // 3. Finally Add barbutton item
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item
    }

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        let url = NSURL.init(string: "http://www.probe-lab.com")
        let items:[Any] = [url!]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [.print, .assignToContact,.saveToCameraRoll,.addToReadingList,.openInIBooks]
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've found a solution, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your custom class i just tested your custom class and run small test case on that, made some changes please have a look. no need to make `var button:UIButton = UIButton()` in share button , just override UIbutton method.I have changed the add target function as well.

```
class shareButton:UIButton{

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    // set myValue before super.init is called
    super.init(frame: frame)

    //self.button.frame = frame
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed1( sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    // set other operations after super.init, if required
    backgroundColor = .red
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

 @objc func buttonPressed1(sender: UIButton) {

 }
}
```